# how to use trigger to set value based on query result

Tags: mysql, trigger

would appreciate any example on how to set value on the added row based on query results from different table.

something like this

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER trigger BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    NEW.value = (select value from table2 where id=NEW.id)
    NEW.value2 = (select value2 from table2 where id=NEW.id)
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks like it should work. I would run one `SELECT` to retrieve both values

## SUGGESTION #1

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER trigger BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    select value,value2
    INTO NEW.value,NEW.value2
    from table2 where id=NEW.id;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

## SUGGESTION #2

If the `value` and `value2` are of datatype `INT`, do the following

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER trigger BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v1,v2 INT;

    select value,value2 INTO v1,v2
    from table2 where id=NEW.id;

    NEW.value  = v1;
    NEW.value2 = v2;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

or do `DECLARE v1,v2 VARCHAR(45);` or whatever datatype is appropriate

Comment: hi, thank you for taking the time to answer.
here is what i wrote look like
`delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER Transfers_trg BEFORE INSERT ON DIDSUM
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
        select SUM(Minutes)
        INTO @NEW.TransferOut
        from Accounting.Transfers where Source_ID=NEW.Customer_ID;
        select SUM(Minutes)
        INTO @NEW.TransferIn
        from Accounting.Transfers where Destination_ID=NEW.Customer_ID;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
`
without the @ i get error undeclared variable new, the trigger creation works but the fileds are not filled.

Comment: `SELECT t.x, t.y INTO NEW.x, NEW.y ...` doesn't work for me in MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, giving me the error message "Undeclared variable: NEW". I've found a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31068) form 2007 describing the same problem. So I guess "SUGGESTION #1" has never worked. In "SUGGESTION #2" I miss the `SET` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on 5.7 +,

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER trigger BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v1,v2 INT;

    select value,value2 INTO v1,v2
    from table2 where id=NEW.id;

    SET NEW.value  = v1;
    SET NEW.value2 = v2;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```